# How do I get my image and div to be on the same line and height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replicate this image: [Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yVbg.png)

My problem is it is turning out like this: 
[My current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0klZ.png)

how would I go about getting it to look right?  Currently I am just making a template so I filled the image color as blue and it will later be replaced with an icon.

```css
/* Float four columns side by side (desktop view)*/
.column {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flip-card {
 background-color: #FFF;
 width: 75%;
 height: 200px;
 color: #fff;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #000;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.dash-title {
 background-color: #000624;
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #000;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.dash-description {
 background-color: #00A0D3;
 width: 65%;
 height: 75%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}


.dash-icon {
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 25%;
 height: 60%
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "tahoma", Times, Serif;
}

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)*/
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }

}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px to 1024px) */
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px){
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }

/* Small devices (767px and below) */
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
      float: left;
    }
    .col-sm-1 {
      width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-2 {
      width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-3 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    .col-sm-4 {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-5 {
      width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-6 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .col-sm-7 {
      width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-8 {
      width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-9 {
      width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-sm-10 {
      width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-sm-11 {
      width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-sm-12 {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TileTemplate.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="column col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Dashboard Title</div>
      <img class="dash-icon"></img>
      <div class="dash-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Dashboard Title</div>
      <img class="dash-icon"></img>
      <div class="dash-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="column col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Dashboard Title</div>
      <img class="dash-icon"></img>
      <div class="dash-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="column col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="dash-title">Dashboard Title</div>
      <img class="dash-icon"></img>
      <div class="dash-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my code so far and any suggestions would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: don't use float, add `vertical-align:top` to the inline-block element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just float: left; in .dash-description class. Clear Float After each flip card

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the HTML to just one card to make things simpler. If you apply flexbox, in the content area of your cards you will have an easier time:

```css
.flip-card {
 color: #fff;
 border: solid 1px #000;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

.flip-card header {
 background-color: #000624;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

.flip-card main{
   display: flex;
   margin: 15px;
}

.flip-card main img{
   max-width: 40%;
}

.flip-card main .dash-description {
 background-color: #00A0D3;
 padding: 10px 0 0 15px;
}

* {
  font-family: "tahoma", Times, Serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
    <header>Dashboard Title</header>
    <main>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200" />
      <div class="dash-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </main>
</div>
```